# using multiple threads to send packets in a socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udp

## intro

I am trying to use threads to send for example **5 packets** using **5 threads** at the same time  *(Making Reliable UDP Selective repeat protocol  I will later add* *acknowledgement and simulate loss)*

I am a beginner to socket programming so I am not sure if this approach is right

All the packets gets send and I re-order then at the client side ( attached with a sequence number to order) 
.

**-I divide the packets into bytes in a list of byte[] and add sequence number**

**-pass each packet to the child function in a new thread to send (MAX 5 threads then wait)**
when I use one thread to send file gets send successful 
but when I use 5 threads to send the same packets file get corrupted 
(data scrambled)

So what happens when two threads calls Socket.Send(data);

does it synchronize?

I Made some test and here are the results
When I wait between each thread start. the problem goes way( the file is received successfully )

I tried making the send function locked so it can only gets accessed by one thread at a time, but that didn't work

all other parts of code are tested so i am sure it is a threads problem

**So how do I use multiple threads to send packets using the same socket ?**

code

```
      for (i = 0; i < pck_count; i++)
    {


  while (EMPTY_THREADS <= 0);//wait for any thread to finish
     //SIZE = windows size = is number of packets to send at one time =                     threads no
 //then try to send SIZE (5) packets from it: 
 int j = 0;
 for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
 {



     if (j + i >= pck_count)
     {
         break;

     }
     //if packet not already sent , send it
     if (!status[i + j].sent && (j + i < pck_count))
     {
        // Console.WriteLine("Sending Packet:" + (i + j) );

         status[i + j].sent = true; //
         status[i + j].ack = true; // TO REMOVE 



         try
         {
             makeThread(Remote, j, i, newsocket);
          //   Thread.Sleep(150); // this makes it work   

         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + e.Message);
         }


     }




}
```

Make Thread:

```
public static void makeThread(EndPoint Remote, int j,int i,Socket newsocket)
    {
        EMPTY_THREADS--;
        thread[j] = new Thread(

               () => startChild(msgs[i + j], Remote, j,newsocket));
        thread[j].Start();

    }
```

child:

```
 static void startChild(myMessage packet, EndPoint Remote, int k,Socket newsocket  )
  {

   Console.WriteLine("Sending PACK" + packet.data.Length +" "+ packet.seq_no);
  byte[] data = new byte[1024];



       newsocket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;

       int sentbytes = 0;

    `//convert packet from object to data array 
       data = serialize(packet);
       newsocket.Connect(Remote);

           sentbytes = newsocket.Send(data);

       //newsocket.Sendto(data,remote); //tried Sendto() with same effect

    //   newsocket.Close();
       EMPTY_THREADS++;
  }
```

Comment: Using multiple threads in this fashion not only _will_ corrupt the data but also is inefficient when each thread will block on the network anyway.  One uses multiple threads for IOCP but such threads are not bound for any particular task or job rather they are multiplexed.  For you simply using `async` and `await` is arguably the better way to go

Comment: You can have only one connection with the following three parameters 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port Number.  When you split a message into multiple threads you must use different port numbers for each thread.  Then add an id to each message thread so it can be combined back into the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

@Micky yes you're right this fashion is wrong and corrupts the data, the solution was to use a single thread and a single socket to send packets in a normal loop, and use threading for timers and acknowledgement only